# How do updates happen with Live streaming in HLS

Tags: http-live-streaming, video.js, m3u8

An HLS manifest contain a master playlist and a media playlist in case of multiple qualities.Only a media playlist is needed in case there are no multiple qualities.As the live stream progresses , the segments of  the video must be running out.

How does the m3u8 manifest gets updated ?

I tried downloading live m3u8 manifest from free live streams after X mins but i see the master playlist as well as the meida playlist.I assume the m3u8 manifest need to get updated regularly by overriding the same media playlist url with more `.ts` segments each time.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`I assume the m3u8 manifest need to get updated regularly by overriding the same media playlist url with more .ts segments each time.`

Exactly. The file is updated and replaced. The player downloads an update regularly. Best practices are documented in the RFC: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8216

Comment: So the list is re-downloaded every 10 seconds if segmentation is made of 10 seconds chunks? Isn't that too inefficient?

Comment: How the hls player will know that there is more to it? If it reaches the end of the playlist it has downloaded, then video will stop, isn't it?